# c# string format 0,0 single digit has leading zero

Tags: c#, string, format

I have a number which I want to format using thousand separator. I'm using format `"0,#.##"`. It works nicely when I have more than single digit. However it added a leading zero when the value is single digit

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string format = "0,#.##";
        
        string strA = "1";
        string strB = "1234";
        
        decimal decA = decimal.Parse(strA);
        decimal decB = decimal.Parse(strB);
        
        string fmtA = decA.ToString(format);
        string fmtB = decB.ToString(format);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Decimal A = " + decA); // displays 1
        Console.WriteLine("Decimal B = " + decB); // displays 1234
        
        Console.WriteLine("Formatted A = " + fmtA); // displays 01
        Console.WriteLine("Formatted B = " + fmtB); // displays 1,234
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the single digit value stays a single digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use one of the following format strings:

```cs
string format = "#,#.##";
string format = "#,0.##";
```

With your original code, this results in:

```
Decimal A = 1
Decimal B = 1234
Formatted A = 1
Formatted B = 1,234
```

The second format above is if you need values like `0.2` to display in that form instead of `.2`. The reason for your observed behaviour can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings):

> "0": Zero placeholder: Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.
>
> "#": Digit placeholder: Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

---

A complete program that shows the behaviour of this, for a variety of data items, is shown below:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string format = "#,0.##";
        
        foreach (string str in new string[] { "1", "1234", "0.2" }) {
            decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str);
            string fmt = dec.ToString(format);
            Console.WriteLine(str + "\n   -> " + dec + "\n   -> " + fmt);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
1
   -> 1
   -> 1
1234
   -> 1234
   -> 1,234
0.2
   -> 0.2
   -> 0.2
```

Comment: Should be noted that if you have a value like `0.2` this will display it as `.2` instead of `0.2`

Comment: @juharr: since that wasn't part of the test data, I'm going to claim compliance. That will need to be a variation on the original contract, for which payment will need to be made :-). On a more serious note, yes, I've adjusted the answer to make that clear, and to provide a solution. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I see.. I forgot that the left side of comma separator is in a same group, even if they're separated by thousand separator. Should be `0,#` instead `#,0`. Thanks a lot.